# Outlook Interop: MailItem stuck in Outbox

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I create a `MailItem` like following:

```
Application outlook = new Application();
NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
Inspector inspector;

AutoResetEvent mailSentEvent;

private void Compose()
{
    MailItem mailItem = outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem));
    inspector = mailItem.GetInspector;

    inspector.Display(false);
    ((InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close += MailItem_Close;

    mailSentEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    mailSentEvent.WaitOne();
}

private void MailItem_Close()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MailItem_Close ...");
    SyncObject syncObject = ns.SyncObjects[1];
    syncObject.SyncEnd += SyncObject_SyncEnd;
    syncObject.Start();
}

private void SyncObject_SyncEnd()
{
    Console.WriteLine("SyncObject_SyncEnd ...");
    mailSentEvent.Set();
}
```

**EDIT**
After user clicks on *Send* the output is

```
MailItem_Close ...
SyncObject_SyncEnd ...
```

**END EDIT**

Problem: after the user clicks *Send*, mail is stuck in outbox *when Outlook is not already running* before `MailItem` is created.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630246/email-sent-from-c-sharp-oom-stays-in-outbox-if-outlook-is-closed-until-next-outl), use of `SyncObject` should avoid this issue. But it doesn't work: when Outlook has not already been running, `MailItem` is stuck in outbox.

What am I missing? Is it possible at all to ensure mail is being sent if Outlook has not been running in advance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.start) method of the `SyncObject` class to begin synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group if it is not perfomed automatically.

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Dim strPrompt As Integer 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
 "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
 syc.Start 
End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

This problem can occur if the Send immediately when connected option is not enabled, as shown in the following figure from Outlook 2016.

[image: Send immediately]

This setting is tied to the following registry data, so this setting can also be configured by an administrator through a modification of the registry.

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
```

or

```
Policy key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Options\Mail

DWORD: Send Mail Immediately
Value: 0
```

Note In the above registry key paths, x.0 represents the Outlook version (16.0 = Outlook 2016, Outlook 2019 or Outlook for Office 365, 15.0 = Outlook 2013, 14.0 = Outlook 2010, 12.0 = Outlook 2007).

There are a lot of reasons why messages can be stuck in the outbox folder - the `Work offline` mode is enabled in Outlook, another Outlook process is hanging in memory and etc.

Comment: Thanks, but Send immediately is active in my Outlook installation. So I guess my problem is related to usage of SyncObject.

Comment: You will never get the `SyncEnd` event fired if the source object declared in the function. You must prevent the source object from being swiped by the garbage collector.

Comment: Even if I declare SyncObject at global level the mail is not being sent and remains in outbox until Outlook is started next time.

Comment: Is the Work offline mode enabled in Outlook?

Comment: No. Work offline isn't enabled.

Comment: see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8/imap-emails-getting-stuck-in-outbox/dd7ef716-65ec-47ad-a17d-df563dfc486f

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `syncObject` variable is declared on the global level, otherwise it will get Garbage Collected.

Also, get rid of the `mailSentEvent.WaitOne()` - it stops your app, and the event will never fire since it needs the Windows message pump to run.

Comment: Even after declaring syncObject at global level (and removing AutoResetEvent) the mail stays in Outbox until Outlook is started next time. See my edits: SyncObject_SyncEnd **is** being called.

Comment: What kind of account are you sending through? Exchange or POP3/SMTP?

Comment: I'm using IMAP/SMTP

Comment: Is that account included in the "All Accounts" Send/Receive group? Have you tried Namespace.SendAndReceive? How many other accounts do you have in the profile?